# How to show database in cake php

Tags: cakephp

I am quite new in CakePHP, I have little knowledge about CakePHP.

I created a database name item in CakePHP, I have also created the fields `id`, `name` , `date`, `priority`, `completed`.

Then I have the following classes:

- `item.php` in `app/models/item.php`
- `items_controller.php` in `app/controllers/items_controller.php`

When I run my code with the url `localhost/cake/item` to see my database table, it is not working. The error message is get is:

```
fatal_Error: unexpected T_CLASS
```

How  i can abell to see my database table & also give me some idea to  how to launch Scaffolding in my url?

Comment: show us your code ... database.php/items_controller.php

Answer (score 0):

Run: localhost/cake/items (pluar form)

By default in URL set the name of controller.

Try now and say it's problem still?

BTW: Do You configure database.php in Config/?

Comment: Ya,i configure database.php in Config. and put the run::localhost/cake/items but there is msg Itemscontroller could not found, plz help me

Comment: Show content of items_controller.php or ItemsController.php file. Which version of Cake You are using?

Comment: I using cake php 2.4.3

Comment: CakePHP v2+ uses CamelCased class names, but in your example you are using v1.3 class names

Answer (score 0):

This issue mostly occures due to two reasons:

```
  1) Check you controller code have written 
     PHP tag like <? php  it should be <?php
  2) check in your model have your written $name="Item" 
     instead of using var $name="Item" or public $name="Item"
```

I think your issue will definitely solved.
If still issue is occurring then post your Controller's code and Model's code also.....